# IIS problem, cannot start Windows Process Activation Service on Windows 10 1909, Error 30

Tags: iis, service

When I try to start service "Windows Process Activation Service",
I get Error 30: The system cannot read from the specified device.

Try to find Error 30 in Google、Baidu，get nothing.

P.S: "C:\inetpub\temp\appPools" is exist, and I give it all permission.

Comment: Use Process Monitor to check if a registry key access is blocked.

Comment: Well, I tried and doesn't look like so.

Comment: IIS will report this error when either your system file or registry has been corrupted.  Process monitor and dump file are required to  find the root cause. If you are not sure how to find out the process monitor log and have a support contract, you can send your VHD to micrsoft support for help.  Besides, have you filtered access denied or access violation/ not found error in process monitor?

Comment: Which process name should I include? Just svchost.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally!!!! I get it done!

1. Find a normal computer(WAS Service is running), backup "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WAS", then back to your computer.
2. run cmd in Admin Mode, run"sc delete WAS".
3. run "sc create WAS binpath="c:\windows\system32\svchost.exe -k iissvcs" DisplayName="Windows Process Activation Service" type=share error=normal start=delayed-auto depend=RPCSS".
4. Restore the registry with your backup.
5. Start WAS Service!